# Angular material form field inside material radio button doesn't trigger radio button

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I have a `form field` within a `radio button`, the radio button does not get selected when clicking on the form field. 
It does get selected if I click within the area of the radio button but outside of the form field.

When I click on the form field, I can see the animation of the radio button is selected but not actually being selected.

Simplified Code:

```
<mat-radio-button>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-radio-button>
```

How do I get the radio button to be selected once the user clicks on the field?

-EDIT-

The `mat-form-field` is mandatory. Or is there a better way of having the radio button being auto selected once the user clicks on the field?

Answer (score 2):

**This uses reactive forms.**

You can just use a normal `(click)` event on the `mat-form-field`.

Because the click event propagates this won't interfere with anything.

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="refundType">

   <mat-radio-button [value]="'partial-refund'" fxLayout="row">

        <mat-form-field appearance="standard" 
                        (click)="selectPartialCheckbox()">

             <mat-label>Partial Refund</mat-label>

             <input matInput [placeholder]="'Amount to refund'" 
                    formControlName="amount"/>

        </mat-form-field>

   </mat-radio-button>

   <!-- other items not shown -->

</mat-radio-group>
```

However you actually set the value depends on exactly how your coding standards go, but something like this:

```
selectPartialCheckbox()
{
    this.form.controls['refundType'].setValue('partial-refund');
}
```

Don't try to check the checkbox in the DOM - that's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**You should try like this:**

```
 <mat-radio-group name="grpName" >
            <mat-radio-button [checked]="true" name="opList1" >Option 1</mat-radio-button>
           <mat-radio-butto name="opList2" >Option 2</mat-radio-button>
           <mat-radio-button name="opList3" >Option 3</mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: I need the form field. The form field is where I am getting the issue where the radio button refuses to be selected. Like in your example, if we replace Option 1 with a mat-form-field, the button doesn't auto select when selecting on the field.

Comment: Why do you need the form field? You should be able to bind both reactive and template driven forms directly to a mat-radio-group. mat-radio-button is not designed to be used with mat-form-field.

Comment: Why do you need a form field? Because the UI works better sometimes. eg. `- Full Refund` followed by `- Partial Refund [_____]` and the user expects to just click in the text box. Why make things harder and hide the text box until the radio has been clicked?